# Ionic 5 push notification with Laravel Echo

Tags: angular, laravel-echo, ionic5

I am writing an App which must contain push notification.
I use Ionic 5(Angular) on frontend and Laravel on backend.
Laravel emits notifications via Echo.

I would like to use this with capacitor:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push

However this description slightly haze&maze...

My list.component.ts looks like the following:

```
// Echo imported
    import {Push, PushObject, PushOptions} from '@ionic-native/push/ngx';

...

    constructor(private push: Push) {
    window.Echo = new Echo.default({
                broadcaster: 'socket.io',
                host: 'https://myhost.eu:6000',
                auth: {
                    headers: {
                        'X-Auth-Token': localStorage.getItem('_token')
                    }
                }
            });
            window.Echo.private('auctions')
                .listen('NewAuctionCreated', (e) => {
                    console.log('in auction');
                    if (e.auction) {
                        e.auction.new = true;
                        this.items.unshift(e.auction);
                        this.playNotification();
                    }
                });
        this.pushNotification();
    }
...

    pushNotification() {
        // push
        // to check if we have permission
        this.push.hasPermission().then((res: any) => {
            if (res.isEnabled) {
                console.log('We have permission to send push notifications');
                console.log(res);
            } else {
                console.log('We do not have permission to send push notifications');
            }
        });


        // Create a channel (Android O and above). You'll need to provide the id, description and importance properties.
        this.push.createChannel({
            id: 'auctions',
            description: 'Auction channel created',
            // The importance property goes from 1 = Lowest, 2 = Low, 3 = Normal, 4 = High and 5 = Highest.
            importance: 5,
            badge: true
        }).then(() => console.log('Channel created'));

        // Delete a channel (Android O and above)
        // this.push.deleteChannel('testchannel1').then(() => console.log('Channel deleted'));

        // Return a list of currently configured channels
        this.push.listChannels().then((channels) => console.log('List of channels', channels));

        // to initialize push notifications
        const options: PushOptions = {
            android: {},
            ios: {
                alert: 'true',
                badge: true,
                sound: 'false'
            },
            windows: {},
            browser: {
                pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
            }
        }

        const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


        pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

        pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));

        pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
}
```

How can I send and receive notifications?
(The Echo parts and the backend works fine)

Comment: For sending notfication its the same thing as backend, all you need is to send an htpp request to the api page in backend to send the notification and put params in it(title,messgage,and maybe image) and that for send notification part. But for recieve notification, in any notification library you want to recieve notfication from, there should be a part in this library that should be connected to firebase ( at least for android ) , like onesignal or maybe signalx is integrated with firebase. Is the library echo you use integrated with Firebase or not? Anyway check its docs and see the javas...

Comment: Javascript part in their docs, maybe there could be a script tag with their api that could be put in index.html , and by that you can access their javascript code through this script tag...